# Issues using wildcards with strings in Dir function VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently working on user customisability in VBA while searching through some other workbooks. I am having issues converting my `FileName` expression in the `Dir()` function into a path directory with the correct backslash after my folder name, and then using wildcards around `File` to allow Dir to search for all occurrences of a keyword. Currently I believe the \ is omitted, and I can't yet tell if my wildcards are working

```
' Modify this folder path to point to the files you want to use.
Folder = InputBox("Enter folder directory of files")

' e.g C:\peter\management\Test Folder
File = InputBox("Enter filename keyword")

'e.g. PLACE
' NRow keeps track of where to insert new rows in the destination workbook.
NRow = 1

' Call Dir the first time, pointing it to all Excel files in the folder path.
FileName = Dir(Folder & "\" & "*" & File & "*")

' Loop until Dir returns an empty string.
Do While FileName <> ""
```

I am assuming my syntax is incorrect for what I am trying to achieve. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:

```
' Modify this folder path to point to the files you want to use.
Folder = InputBox("Enter folder directory of files")

' e.g C:\peter\management\Test Folder

File = InputBox("Enter filename keyword")

'e.g. PLACE
' NRow keeps track of where to insert new rows in the destination workbook.
NRow = 1

' Call Dir the first time, pointing it to all Excel files in the folder path.
FileName = Dir(Folder & "\" & File & "*" & ".xls")

Debug.Print (FileName)
' Loop until Dir returns an empty string.
Do While FileName <> ""
```

Is what I am currently working with. The "\" in my Dir line doesn't seem to do anything as I still have to add the final \ before the file manually for it to appear in my error message.

Comment: What is the file extension?

Comment: .xls, though shouldn't this be covered by the wildcard?

Comment: use `FileName = Dir(Folder & "\" & File & ".*")`

Comment: That would depend on whether there are filenames for things like PDFs that match the same wildcard used to locate the XLSs.

Comment: why can't you tell if the the code is working?

Comment: Currently the folder has 4 files in it, all of which are .xls and have the keyword I am trying to use in it in the format of PLACE.xls, PLACE (2).xls and so on. When I don't use input boxes and simple set the folder as C:\peter\management\Test Folder\ and the file as * PLACE * it works fine, but I would prefer to avoid making the user enter the extra characters if they are to use their own variables/directory.

Comment: @jsotola in debug mode the code skips straight past the Do While loop which I assume means there is no such filename in the directory/ the directory doesn't exist.

Comment: Have you checked the value of `FileName` just before the first call to dir?

Comment: I tried to recreate the problem, tried with input boxes and then setting the folder in the code and both work fine. Stumped on this one! All I can think is that the folder entered in the inputbox might be slightly off?

Comment: @destination-data `FileName` becomes the first file I want, PLACE-RVG.xls , and then in the Do While loop it gives the error `C:\peter\management\Test Folder\PLACE cannot be found`. I am guessing I am using my variables incorrectly?

Comment: Use option explicit e define every variable, especially the filename variable

Comment: Have you considered the Application.FileDialog? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-filedialog-property-excel

Comment: How are you looping?

Comment: in this statement _"have to add the final \ before the file manually for it to appear in my error message"_  .... what does _"manually"_ mean? ....  what does _"error message"_ mean?

Comment: @jsotola manually means typing including it in the user input for `Folder = InputBox("Enter folder directory of files")` i.e. C:\peter\management\Test Folder\ (with the final \ on at the end). The error message is an excel error pop up window with the error quoted above.

Comment: replace this line `FileName = Dir(Folder & "\" & File & "*" & ".xls")`  ..... with these four lines `dim aaa as string`  ..... `aaa = Folder & "\" & File & "*" & ".xls"`  ..... `debug.print aaa` ..... `FileName = aaa`  ...... please report what prints

Comment: @jsotola thanks for all the help, I found an inconsistency in my naming of files which was causing the final problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried your code it worked for me.  Needless to say, that makes it a little tricky to provide a satisfactory answer!

Below is my attempt to solve the same problem.

Instead of asking the user to manually type the folder address I've used [Excel's built-in folder picker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-filedialog-property-excel).  This avoids the need to check for and deal with typos.

```
Sub FindFiles()
    Dim fldDialog As FileDialog         ' Holds a reference to the folder picker.
    Dim path As String                  ' Folder selected by user.
    Dim fileFilter As String            ' Provided by user, wildcard supported.
    Dim found As String                 ' Used to display returned results.

    ' Config dialog.
    Set fldDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    fldDialog.Title = "Pick a folder"       ' Caption for dialog.
    fldDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False      ' Limit to one folder.
    fldDialog.InitialFileName = "C:\"       ' Default starting folder.

    ' Display to user.
    If fldDialog.Show Then

        ' Config filter.
        path = fldDialog.SelectedItems(1)
        fileFilter = InputBox("Select a filter (*.*)", "File filter", "*.*")

        ' Get results.
        found = Dir(path & "\" & fileFilter)
        Do Until found = vbNullString

            MsgBox found, vbInformation, "File found"
            found = Dir()
        Loop
    Else

        MsgBox "User pressed cancel", vbInformation, "Folder picker"
    End If
End Sub
```